# Spring Data Redis -- How to have alias name for the variable in spring data redis?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, redis, spring-data, spring-data-redis

In the below code if I want to store the id as student_id and name as student_name in redis database and I don't want to change the name of variable in my java code. Is there any way out to provide alias name for the variable as we do in spring data jpa we specify the name of the column in @Column annotation. Please help me out if anyone has the solution for the same.

```
@RedisHash("Student")
public class Student implements Serializable
{
   @Id
   private Long id;
   private String name;

   private float marksObtained;
   private String schoolName;
}
```